# QML MenuItem Highlighted doesn't work

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

Please can someone explain me one thing. Suppose I have an item, if I click it, then a drop-down menu appears. How to make that when you hover over menu items, they stand out like that?

Code:

```
Rectangle {
    id: main_window
    width: 600
    height: 600
    property int mrg: 10   

    Rectangle {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: 500
        height: 500
        color: 'green'

        Text {
            id: field
            text: "Click!"
            font.pointSize: 20
            color: 'white'
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            MouseArea {
                id: ma
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true

                onClicked: {
                    menu.x = ma.mouseX
                    menu.open()
                }
            }

            Menu {
                id: menu
                y: field.height
                MenuItem {
                    text: "Menu item"
                    highlighted: true

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the documentation, I came across the point that the proper `highlight` is responsible for selecting the appropriate menu item. I installed it in the True, but it did not change anything. 
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `MenuItem` doesn't include any visual highlighting feature, but you can adapt the graphical representation to your needs as explained in the [Qt manuals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-menuitem). So, your `MenuItem` should look like this:

```
MenuItem {
    id: control
    text: "Menu item"

    background: Item {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 1
            color: control.highlighted ? "blue" : "transparent" // blue background if the control is highlighed
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true // enable mouse enter events when no mouse buttons are pressed
                onContainsMouseChanged: control.highlighted = containsMouse // set the highlighted flag when the mouse hovers the MenuItem
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation is based on the [default implementation](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/MenuItem.qml?h=dev#n82) provided by Qt:

> ```
> background: Item {
>     implicitWidth: 200
>     implicitHeight: 40
>
>     Rectangle {
>         x: 1
>         y: 1
>         width: parent.width - 2
>         height: parent.height - 2
>         color: control.visualFocus || control.down ? Default.delegateColor : "transparent"
>     }
> }
> ```

*Note that [Bob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56653957/7621674) simplifies this solution by eliminating the `MouseArea`*

Answer (score 3):

Although it's an old question, I came across this as it was something I was wanting to do myself. I think [m7913d](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7621674/m7913d)'s answer can be simplified a little by making use of the `hovered` property of `MenuItem`.

```
MenuItem {
    id: control
    text: "Menu item"
    hoverEnabled: true

    background: Item {
        implicitWidth: 200
        implicitHeight: 40

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 1
            color: control.hovered ? "blue" : "transparent"
        }
    }
}
```

The other thing I did was to retain the `control.down` handling of the original implementation, so the `color` expression is slightly more involved than shown here.